# Rails 4.0.1 JavaScript Asset Pipeline - Cross Browser Support - Loading Issue

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I am working on a rails 4.0.1 application.

I have a a set of interactive slides, intended to teach personal finance. I have a list of question and buttons that when clicked show a jQuery Modal popup window.

My javascript files aren't loading after I perform a <%= link_to %> the next slide with Safari and Mozilla. There is no issues with Chrome.

If I reload the page, the modal does magically start working again. Here is the files that I believe are related. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**application.html.erb**

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

**routes.rb**

```
  match '/slide1',  to: 'interest_rates#slide1', via: 'get'
  match '/slide2',  to: 'interest_rates#slide2', via: 'get'
  match '/slide3',  to: 'interest_rates#slide3', via: 'get'
  match '/slide4',  to: 'interest_rates#slide4', via: 'get'
  match '/slide5',  to: 'interest_rates#slide5', via: 'get'
  match '/slide6',  to: 'interest_rates#slide6', via: 'get'
```

**application.js**

```
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery
//= require d3.v3
//= require d3.layout
//= require rickshaw
//= require custom
//= require graph
```

**slide1.html.erb**

```
 <%= link_to "Next", {:controller => :interest_rates, :action => :slide2}, class: "button" %>
```

Comment: You should really be doing something like `match '/slide/:id', to: 'interest_rate_slides#show', via: :get`, instead of defining a bunch of routes which vary only by a single number.

Comment: Are you getting any error on browser console ?

Comment: What do you mean by "aren't loading"? If your `<script>` is in the `<head>`, Turbolinks will intentionally prevent your browser from loading the script on navigation.

Comment: https://fiscalfitness.herokuapp.com

Comment: There are no errors in the console. The javascript files have not been loaded.

Comment: Turbolinks has been completely removed from the application now and the problem is persisting. When I click on a link_to another html page, the javascript is not loading. There are not errors in the console, because the page has not found the js file. This error only happen in production.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, maybe check out the jquery-turbolinks gem and therubyracer gem. I've had issues where javascript wasn't loading properly, and after using the jquery-turbolinks gem, everything worked.

In my gemfile:

```
gem "jquery-turbolinks", "~> 2.0.1"

gem 'therubyracer', :require => 'v8'
```